# Minimum cost to repair road

Tags: sorting, dynamic-programming, greedy, np

Let us assume there is highway

There are N potholes at points [p1, p2, p3...., pn]

There are equal number of service crew at points [s1, s2, s3...., sn]

One service crew can repair one pothole only

The cost to send a crew at point `pX` to repair a pothole at point `sX` is `|pX-sX|`

How would you find the minimum cost to repair the road?

Ex:

Potholes are at `[3, 5, 7]`

Service Crew are stationed at `[1, 3, 5]`

Few possible combinations are:

`1->3, 3->5, 5->7` (Cost = 6)

`1->5, 3->7, 5->3` (Cost = 10)

Share/Explain the algorithm you'd use to solve this problem?

What is the time & space complexity of your algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example it should be 6, no matter what!

This is the problem of finding maximum matching in a **fully connected bipartite graph**.

If the problem has same number of potholes and crews, it's a **perfect matching**.

- Intention would be to find out maximum matching between potholes P and crews C.
- Assumption: A pothole can be serviced by any crew.
- Matching condition: `|P(i) - C(j)|` is minimum.

Comment: could you share an algorithm to do this?

Comment: take a look here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/matching.pdf

Comment: Sort Potholes and Crews by ascending order.  Iterate lists and sum | Pothole[x] - Crews[x] |